# Creating backups on Alwayson without differential backups

Tags: backup, availability-groups, ola-hallengren

I went through [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143825/any-disadvantage-to-automatically-changing-full-backup-on-alwayson-secondary-to) link on stack exchange and also [Brent Ozar's](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/how-to-configure-alwayson-ag-backups-with-ola-hallengrens-scripts/) . I don't plan to create any differential backups for the AAG group. Can you please let me know if enabling this option should work. I will be adding a new database for an application, and I then plan to create and schedule Ola's scripts. Is it true that for new databases, only full backup happens and not the log backup? What can I do to resolve the issue? Please let know. Thanks!

Comment: Why won't you use a differential backup? What's your reasoning?

Comment: All the applications running on the SQL  server are 3rd party vendor apps which are not revenue critical. Therefore only log backups and full backups are been taken as of now

Answer (score 1):

> . I don't plan to create any differential backups for the AAG group. Can you please let me know if enabling this option should work.

Yes, it'll work.

> Is it true that for new databases, only full backup happens and not the log backup?

I don't understand the question. If it's specific to Ola's script then I do not know, if it's a SQL Server question then you must take at least one full backup and one log backup before adding the database to the AG, so the answer would be no it isn't true.

> What can I do to resolve the issue?

I currently do not see an issue. It's a valid backup strategy, now where or not it meets your recovery SLA in a disaster is another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out "How should I configure DatabaseBackup to back up an Availability Group?" on https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html

Comment: Thank you. So I followed what Brentozar mentioned with Olla hallengren and configured it on all the 3 modes. When I try to execute the job to test it, the job is failing. It says "unexpected parameter". The code I used in the job step is

Answer (score 0):

I am posting what I tried because, the comment section is not allowing me to post what I tried due to the "@" symbols

My code :

This is the code : sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d master -Q “EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = ‘USER_DATABASES’, @Directory = N ’\SQL02\backups’, @BackupType = ‘FULL’, @Verify = ‘Y’, @CleanupTime = NULL, @Copyonly = ‘Y’, @LogToTable = ‘Y'” -b

Comment: Could you script out the job and send that to me.
https://ola.hallengren.com/contact.html

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. I have emailed you the job script!